# Support for concat in JSON Jolt in Apache NiFi

Tags: json, apache-nifi, jolt

Using Apache NiFi I want to add a new field to all the elements within a JSON flow file based on the concatenation of two other fields. I am trying to use the `JoltTransformJSON` processor for this, however, the Jolt transform I want to use works OK using online [tools](http://jolt-demo.appspot.com/#inception) but does not work within NiFi. I suspect a version issue but there may be something stupid with my Jolt specification.

The input JSON looks like this...

```
[
  {
    "id": 485842,
    "cc": 1,
    "x": 0,
    "y": null
  },
  {
    "id": 281733,
    "cc": 1,
    "x": 0,
    "y": 10
  },
  {
    "id": 721412,
    "cc": 12,
    "x": 0,
    "y": null
  }
]
```

The desired output I want is this...

```
[ {
  "id" : 485842,
  "cc" : 1,
  "x" : 0,
  "y" : null,
  "id_cc" : "485842_1"
}, {
  "id" : 281733,
  "cc" : 1,
  "x" : 0,
  "y" : 10,
  "id_cc" : "281733_1"
}, {
  "id" : 721412,
  "cc" : 12,
  "x" : 0,
  "y" : null,
  "id_cc" : "721412_12"
} ]
```

And the Jolt transform I use on the online [site](http://jolt-demo.appspot.com/#inception) is...

```
[{
  "operation": "modify-default-beta",
  "spec": {
    "*": {
      "id_cc": "=concat(@(1,id),'_',@(1,cc))"
    }
  }
}]
```

In NiFi, I configure the `JoltTransformJSON` processor to have `Modify-Default` and I use this slightly modified Jolt Specification...

```
{
    "operation": "modify-default",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "id_cc": "=concat(@(1,id),'_',@(1,cc))"
      }
    }
}
```

NiFi validates this OK and the process runs. The output JSON consists of a single record only and a new field is added like this

```
"operation": "modify-default"
```

Is there a quick fix to the modify-default operation that will resolve this or is there an even easier way using a shift operation?

Thanks in advance for any pointers.

Comment: You can use QueryRecord processor with select (SELECT id, cc, x, y, CAST(id AS VARCHAR) || '_' || CAST(cc AS VARCHAR) AS id_cc FROM FLOWFILE). I'll write answer later.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After some help from colleagues, I have found a way to make this work.

Firstly, set the `Jolt Transformation DSL` property of the `JoltTransformJSON` processor to be `Chain`.

Secondly, set the Jolt specification to the following...

```
[{
    "operation": "modify-default-beta",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "id_cc": "=concat(@(1,id),'_',@(1,cc))"
      }
    }
}]
```

The `[]` are vital as is the `beta` in the operation.

Thirdly, ensure the JSON fed into the Jolt processor is an array.

Get all this correct and the expected output will be produced.